# Why do I have to draw a big triangle to determine the gradient of a straight line using the slope triangle method?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, data-analysis

I'm an igsce student, I'm taking igsce OL phyiscs.

It's stated in my book that after I draw a graph and the line of best fit, I should get the gradient by choosing two points then form a right angel triangle with them, ***where the length of the hypotenuse of the triangle should be greater than half of the length of the line which has been drawn.***

Which makes no sense, the line of best fit is a straight line. The gradient is constant everywhere and I'm only taking points that lie on it as the book also states:

> If plots are used which have been taken from the table of results then they must lie on the line of best fit (to within half a small square)

So why does the triangle have to be big?

I thought maybe so it's easy to measure the distances but I don't have to get the horizontal distance and vertical one, just getting the slope using the x and y coordinates of the two points will still get me the mark.

Does it by somehow decrease the probability of getting it wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the slope of a straight line fitting some data points? To physicists, “gradient” means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient).

Comment: Yes that's what I mean I'll add a picture. This didn't cross my mind I didn't know this was called gradient.

Comment: Can I rephrase your question for clarity, and you tell me if I have it right or wrong? You have drawn an x-y scatter plot with some number of data points, and you have a best fit line drawn on the plot (say, determined by least squares). You want to determine the slope of the line. So your book suggests to take two points on the line and form a right triangle, with the hypotenuse being the best fit line and the legs being parallel to the x and y axes. However, your book also suggests the hypotenuse should be at least half as long as the best fit line, and you want to know why. ?

Comment: @yeah that's exactly what I mean Andrew

Comment: If you have the equation for a best fit line determined by least squares, then why not just use the coefficient of the linear term in the fit as that would be the slope?

Comment: I would love to do so straight away, as I said before I don't even measure the lengths so I'm not really using it. I calculate the gradient by subtracting the coordinates of the points I chose. But that annoying triangle is needed to be drawn to get the mark. I think it's because I'm still an OL student and they need to make sure that we have certain skills acquired, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you picture, you can measure the rise $Y=y_2-y_1$ and the run $X=x_2-x_1$ using a ruler. Let's say your ruler has a constant error $\Delta X = \Delta Y = \delta$.

You measure the slope $S$ as
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{Y}{X}
\end{equation}
The error in the slope can be found by error propagation
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta S &=& \sqrt{ \left( \frac{1}{X}\right)^2 \Delta Y^2 + \left(\frac{Y}{X^2}\right)^2 \Delta X^2 } \\
&=& \sqrt{1+S^2} \frac{\delta}{X}
\end{eqnarray}

Now we can write the length of the hypotenuse $h$ as $h = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} = X \sqrt{1+S^2} $, so

\begin{equation}
\Delta S = (1+S^2) \frac{\delta}{h}
\end{equation}

Now, the factor of $1+S^2$ and $\delta$ are things you can't really control. These are the slope of the line you've happened to draw, and the error on your ruler, respectively.

On the other hand, by taking a larger $h$ (ie a bigger triangle), you reduce the error in the slope, $\Delta S$. This should make intuitive sense, your measurement of a longer line will have less uncertainty due to the tick marks on the ruler than a shorter line.

The idea of taking $h$ to be at least half of the original hypotenuse is somewhat arbitrary, as far as I can tell. The net result is that your error is within a factor of 2 of the best possible error you could get, using the entire line. In other words, if the true hypotenuse had length $H$, then...

\begin{equation}
h \geq \frac{H}{2} \implies \Delta S_h  \leq 2 \Delta S_H = 2 (1+S^2) \frac{\delta}{H}
\end{equation}

where $\Delta S_h$ is the error you get with $h$ and $\Delta S_H$ the error you get with $H$. In other words, you are unnecessarily penalizing yourself by using a smaller triangle to measure the slope.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm new to the error propagation concept and its rules but I googled it to really understand your answer.  But I didn't get this part, though: *This should make intuitive sense, your measurement of a longer line will have less uncertainty due to the tick marks on the ruler than a shorter line.* What does the drawn lines on the ruler (if that's what you meant by the word "tick") have to do with the length of the line drawn and the uncertainty. I even googled the error produced by the ruler but only discovered it's because of the placement of it at the zero mark.

Comment: And we will have the same zero error even if the line is short or long, won't we?

Comment: @Manar, for the same of the argument, assume that there is as much as 1/2 mm error at $(x_1,y_2)$ and at $(x_2,y_2)$.  If those two points are close together, the slope calculation will have a lot of uncertainty in it.  If those points are far apart, the slope calculation will have much less error in it.  You can easily convince yourself of this if you set up a "test" where you introduce a given error in the points used to calculate a known slope.

Comment: I'm just going to say what @DavidWhite said in a slightly different way. Imagine you have meterstick with mm markings. If you measure something that is one mm long, you are going to have a large *relative error*, since your uncertainty in the length (roughly half a mm) is close to the size of the thing you are trying to measure. If you measure something 50 cm long, your *absolute error* will be the same, but the *relative error* will be smaller. You can be very confident the true length of the thing is somewhere in the range 49.5-50.5 cm, and the range of 1mm is small compared to 50 cm.

Comment: Also I think the most important thing to understand from the answer is this bit of intuition. The error propagation calculations are nice to understand but if you don't have the intuition then the calculation won't make much sense.